# Fourth order statistic on a continuous pdf $f(x) = 3x^2$ when $0<x<1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, order-statistics

> The random variable $X$ has pdf $f(x) = 3x^2$ when $0<x<1$ and $0$ otherwise. A sample size $n = 6$ is to be taken. Determine the density of $X_{(4)}$, the fourth order statistic.

I tried$$\int \frac{6!}{2!3!}  f(x)F(x)^4(1-F(x))^2$$
where $F(x)$ is the integral of $f(x)$ from $0$ to $x$, but was marked wrong

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? I think they usually give you a formula to plug into. Have you looked at it?

Comment: I tried $\int \frac{6!}{2!3!}  f(x)F(x)^4(1-F(x))^2$ where F(x) is the integral of f(x) from 0 to x, but was marked wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost right. There was no need to take the integral. The general formula for the density of the $k$th order statistic of $n$ iid random variables with PDF $f$ and CDF $F$ is 
$$f_{(k)}(x) = \frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!} f(x) [F(x)]^{k-1}[1-F(x)]^{n-k}$$
for $-\infty< x<\infty$. You can find the proof in any standard textbook.

---

You were given that the common density is
$$ f(x) = 3x^2$$
when $0<x<1$. For $0<x<1$, we have
$$F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\,dt = \int_0^x3t^2\,dt =  x^3.$$

Now you just plug into the formula for $f_{(k)}(x)$.

Comment: does it matter if it's a pdf or a cdf? Because in my question it's a pdf, but you assumed it was a cdf.

Comment: I didn't assume "it" was anything. You have a pdf and from that you can derive the cdf. That's how you apply the formula I gave. Isn't that what you meant in your attempt?

Comment: I updated my answer. Does that clarify your confusion?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: That formula looks awfully reminiscent to a binomial mass function. Is there a connection?

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 Kind of? I don't want to butcher it, but in my mind it's always been kind of like a multinomial distribution, but that's probably a gross mischaracterization. Take a look at this post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1650081/how-does-one-find-the-density-of-the-kth-ordered-statistic) where the counting arguments were discussed.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 I usually write it, but the counting factor in my mind should be $\binom{n}{k-1, 1, n-k} = \frac{n!}{(k-1)!\cdot 1! \cdot (n-k)!}$ for this problem. This is especially helpful if you're trying to find the joint distribution of more than one order statistic.

Answer (score 0):

Given

$$f(x) = 3x^2$$
$$F(x) = x^3 $$

when $0<x<1$.

The pdf of the $r$th order statistic is given by

$$f_{r:n}(x)_=\frac{n !}{(r - 1)! (n - r)!} F(x)^{r-1} (1-F(x))^{n-r} f(x)$$

We just plug $f(x)$ and $F(x)$ into the above for $n=6$ and $r=4$, and we get

$$g_{4:6}(x)=180 x^{11} \left(x^3-1\right)^2$$

with cdf

$$
G_{4:6}(x) =\begin{array}{cc}
 \left\{ 
\begin{array}{cc}
 x^{12} \left(10 x^6-24 x^3+15\right) & 0<x<1 \\
  1 & x\geq 1\\
\end{array}
 \\
\right.
\end{array}
$$

${\bf EDIT}:$

For the "fun of it", let's find a formula for the expected values of the rth order statistic given 6 samples...

It turns out that

$$E[X_{r:6}] = \frac{720 \Gamma \left(r+\frac{1}{3}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{22}{3}\right) \Gamma (r)}$$