# Distribution of Ordered statistics.

Tags: order-statistics

We are given a sample of size $n$ ($X_i$), the ordered statistics are as follows:

$Y_1\leq Y_2 \leq Y_3$. .  .     .      .$Y_{n-1}\leq Y_n$

I am trying to establish the the probability density function of $\alpha$th ordered statistic i.e $f_{Y_{\alpha}}(y)$.

The solution goes as follows:

$f_{Y_{\alpha}}(y)=\lim_{\Delta y->0}\dfrac{F_{Y_{\alpha}}(y+\Delta y)-F_{Y_{\alpha}}(y)}{\Delta y}$

= $\lim_{\Delta y->0}\dfrac{P(y<X_i\leq y+\Delta y)}{\Delta y}$

= $lim_{\Delta y->0}\dfrac{P((\alpha -1)\:of\:X_i \leq y;one\:X_i \: in\: (y,y+\Delta];(n-\alpha)\:of\:X_i > y+\Delta y)}{\Delta y}$

Now, let $N$ be the number of $X_i 's$ such that $X_i\leq y$, thus $N$~$Bin(n,F_{X_i}(y))$.

Also, let $N^{'}$ be the number of $X_i 's$ such that $X_i> y+\Delta y$, thus $N^{'}$~$Bin(n,1-F_{X_i}(y))$.

Thus, $f_{Y_{\alpha}}(y)=lim_{\Delta y ->0}\dfrac{(\binom{n}{\alpha -1}[F(y)]^{\alpha -1}[1-F(y)]^{n-\alpha})(F(y+\Delta y)-F(y))(\binom{n}{n-\alpha}[F(y)]^{\alpha}[1-F(y)]^{n-\alpha})}{\Delta y}$

Following this, I am not able to get the correct answer which is $\dfrac{n!}{(\alpha -1)!(n-\alpha)!}[F(y)]^{\alpha-1}[1-F(y)]^{n-\alpha}f(y)$

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1650097/148510) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1179378/148510)

Comment: This method not good ? @RRL

Comment: Well we know that the PDF is the derivative of the CDF: $f_{Y_a}(y) = \frac{d}{dy} F_{Y_a}(y)$.  You  start pursuing this by writing the definition of the derivative, but it's not going anywhere for you, since you have not clearly expressed the CDF.  The first link shows that $F_{Y_a}(y) = \sum_{j=a}^{n} {{n}\choose{a}}[F(x)]^j[1-F(x)]^{n-j}$.  Now you take the derivative, which is not trivial to reduce, but explained in the second link.

Comment: Got the proof in the link you provided, but I was stuck on the proof above for like $1\frac{1}{2}$ days, I thought I was close to the solution, well, never mind, thanks anyway ! @RRL