# Doubt in order statistics theory?

Tags: density-function, order-statistics

Note : The equation is taken from a paper titled "Performance Analysis of Monostatic Multi-Tag Backscatter Systems With General Order Tag Selection" and given reference is of "Order Statistics" by H.A.David.

I am trying to derive the following equation (1) using order statistics theory.

Let $Z$ =r-th max ($\gamma_1,\gamma_2...\gamma_m$) where $m=1,2,...,M$ and the PDF, CDF of $\gamma_m$ is: $f_{\gamma_m}(z)$=$\frac{\zeta\cdot e^{-\zeta\sqrt{z}}}{2\sqrt{z}}u(z)$ and $F_{\gamma_m}(z)=1-e^{-\zeta\sqrt{z}}u(z)$. Then using these above PDF and CDF of $\gamma_m$ and using order statistics theory, the PDF of $Z$ is $f_Z(z)= r\binom{M}{r}\frac{\zeta\cdot e^{-\zeta r \sqrt{z}}(1-e^{-\zeta\sqrt{z}})^{M-r}}{2\sqrt{z}}u(z)$ ---(1).

My doubt is how the equation (1) is coming. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: It seems you are quoting from a particular book or PDF. It will be very helpful if you can provide the source, since I'd like to know the rest of the material (although I thank you very much for typing out what you wished to isolate). You may edit your question and provide the source (textbook/PDF/paper/slideshow). We would be able to explain this only with that relevant background. If you ask me, I feel like I can make out elements of $f_{\gamma_m}$ and $F_{\gamma_m}$ in the expression for $f_Z$, but it's not completely clear how to make it work at first glance.

Comment: Yes it is taken from research paper titled "Performance Analysis of Monostatic Multi-Tag Backscatter Systems With General Order Tag Selection" and in this it gives the reference of "Order Statistics by H.A. David".

Comment: Great! Please give me permission to edit this into the question. I'll try to see if I can figure out the answer.

Comment: Yes sure... you can edit the question.

Comment: Thank you very much. It turns out there is a post on Math Stackexchange which contains the pdf of general order statistics. It is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1179371/how-to-find-distribution-of-order-statistic), along with a full derivation. I took about 15 minutes to find it! When I substituted it into the expression, I got $r \binom{M}{r} \frac{\zeta \cdot e^{-\zeta\cdot z}}{2 \sqrt{z}} u(z) \times (e^{-\zeta \sqrt {z}}u(z))^{M-r} (1-e^{-\zeta \sqrt {z}}u(z))^{r-1}$, which is slightly off if there is no typo in your expression. I'll confirm this from the paper.

Comment: Thank you so much ... will check the link..

Comment: Sure, let me know how it goes. Furthermore, I found that $u$ is the unit step function, so basically powers of $u$ reduce to $u$ itself. When I took all the $u$s out , I could see immediately the equation $(1)$ coming out correctly.(Note : I just realized I made a small error in my expression in the above comment : the $r-1$ should be switched with the $M-r$.)

Comment: Finally derived.....Thanks for your support to the newbie like me..

Comment: It was good to be of help to you!